# Multilingual using objective c in xcode7

Tags: objective-c, xcode, multilingual

I wanted to add a switch language function in my application without changing devices's language. Is that possible to perform multilingual without using localize? Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: there are many iOS localization libraries available in Github. Have you tried any of them?

Comment: I googled, but all the method from there required changing your device's language. I only wan internal language switch instead of whole device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
however you must handle the localization process all by yourself.

Basically, you need to create function to localize string, preferably if you create extension to NSString so you can call it anywhere and save the language picked.
You also need to provide localizable.string for every language that your app supported.
Don't use localization provided by storyboard. You need to wire every element that you want to localize into your code and change the text via the NSString extension.

Comment: Since I'm still beginner, can i create more VC in diff language to perform multilingual ? Is this way work?

Comment: you shouldn't create more VC just to make localization. Just connect your outlet to your code and change the text in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

These seem to do in-app language switching:

- https://cocoapods.org/pods/BRLocalize
- https://cocoapods.org/pods/Localize-Swift

However I've used neither of them & can't vouch for their usefulness.